# Destiny - The Taken King / Rise of Iron help!

Tags: destiny

I was REALLY into destiny on release, I played up until House of Wolves came out and played that for a bit, got to level 34 but I had really gotten bored of the content by that point.

I have three characters, level 32,33 and 34 and I have just bought the collection to play TTK and ROI.

Where do I start? There is so much new stuff I had about 30 pop ups about various things when I got in the game I am just lost!

What major things do I need to know about since HOW dropped?

I know this question is a massive ask but the game I once knew inside out, I now feel lost in.

Comment: I feel like these 4 points might be better as separate questions. Right now it's a bit too broad.

Comment: @Jutschge duly noted, lets focus on my confusion first of all! I suppose levelling and exotics I can focus on once I have got to grips with the changes!

Comment: Go through TTK story to acquire your characters third subclass. Either experience the rest of TTK or skip to iron lords for better gearing. Become familiar with the new missions page and record books. They are there to help keep track of current tasks and you will get gear by completing some of them. Strike playlists have been revamped including new bounties available at Zavala and the bounty master. Cosmetic microtransactions have been added in the form of eververse. You can find the stands in the Tower or the Iron Temple. That's just some stuff i can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Returning Players Guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/wiki/returningplayers) on Reddit is probably a good place to start.

To summarize the bigger changes I can remember off hand:

- All of your missions / quests / things to do are on the Quests tab of your inventory. It is one screen to the left of your gear.
- There is a new leveling system. You were probably level 20 / light level 34 when you stopped playing. Now you are likely level 34 with a light level somewhere around 160 - 170. You should do about the same damage as before. Each light level still increases your damage, but it isn't as much as under the old system. The current max level is 40, and max light level is 400.
- You can no longer re-roll weapons (any weapons from the HoW era can still be re-rolled). You can re-roll exotic armor using Glass Needles, which are purchased from Xur.
- All Year 2 (and later) weapons and armor can be infused. For example, if you have a pulse rifle with 290 light and you find another primary weapon with 300 light, you can infuse the new weapon into the old weapon and the old pulse rifle will now be 300 light.
- All weapons and armor from Year 1 can't be infused - they are stuck at Year 1 light levels.
- Class items are no longer only cosmetic - they have stats, including Light.
- Motes of Light can now level up your gear. If you use a mote from the inventory screen, any weapons and armor you have equipped will gain XP.
- All the old Year 1 materials that aren't used anymore (ascendent shards, raidant shards, etc.) can be exchanged for other materials at the Speaker.
- In order to gain reputation with a faction, you need to Pledge with that faction. You can only change the faction you are pledged to once per week (reset at the weekly reset). This costs 2500 glimmer up front (I think), but after that it doesn't cost anything to change. You don't need to wear that faction's class item to get rep for them - you always get rep for the faction and Vanguard or Crucible (depending on the activity).
- The stat rolls on vendor items change each week at the weekly reset.

That's all I can think of off hand. Again, the Returning Players Guide likely summarizes this better than I can. If you have any other specific questions, either ask new questions on the site or if they are related to this post a comment.

Comment: Thanks for that, the link to the guide was very helpful too!